# source list problem after upgrade to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, software-sources

I upgraded my ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 , then after unit reboot I get my sources 14.04 back .

In sources.list I get **trusty** sources instead of **vivid** sources

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use a sources list generator](http://askubuntu.com/questions/501796/how-to-use-a-sources-list-generator)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found fix to my question . I work in cloud environment . It was script that changed repository list after each reboot . Cloud team is owner of this script

Comment: See my improved answer.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `trusty` with `vivid` in the files `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`

1. Check the result with:

   ```
   sudo find /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ -type f -name "*.list" | sed 's/trusty/vivid/' /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo sed 's/trusty/vivid/' /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```
2. If it's OK, start `sed` with inline editing `-i`

   ```
   sudo find /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ -type f -name "*.list" | sed -i 's/trusty/vivid/' /etc/apt/sources.list
   sudo sed -i 's/trusty/vivid/' /etc/apt/sources.list
   ```

and if it changes after each reboot, and you don't remember which tool did this, just add the above to your `Startup Applications`.

Comment: Thanks . My problem that after reboot some tool restore old sources list