# I have been trying to install vlc media player on ubuntu 16.04 LTS but keep facing this problem.Can anyone suggest me something?

Tags: software-installation

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.7 but it is not going to be installed
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libqt5x11extras5 (>= 5.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libsdl-image1.2 (>= 1.2.10) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libva-drm1 (>= 1.1.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libva-x11-1 (>= 1.0.3) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libvlccore8 (>= 2.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-composite0 but it is not going to be installed
       Depends: libxcb-xv0 (>= 1.2) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.2-5ubuntu0.16.04.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: You've already been suggested to run `sudo apt-get -f install`, have you not?

Comment: Actually,I tried.It`s not working.The problem remains the same.

Comment: I have been facing this problem while installing mysql and mongodb too.

Comment: What repositories are you using )please update your question and post them) libqt5x11extras5 is not available outside artful, so I suspect a ppa or mixed repos.

Comment: @Terrance Everything you said has been enabled in the settings,still things did not change.

Comment: or you can use this https://askubuntu.com/questions/501796/how-to-use-a-sources-list-generator , to generate a new repository.

Comment: You will have to file a bug report with the  ppa -  ppa:videolan/master-daily

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`sudo apt-get -f install`

`-f` to fix the broken dependencies. After this do run the following:

`sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Then again

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: I tried this,but the problem remains the same.

Comment: i have been facing this problem while installing mongodb and mysql too.

Comment: try this link https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa

Comment: @hbeast - You really need to update your question with that information as it was asked in the comments and relevant to your problem. I also wish to examine your repos , see my comment above.

Comment: @Panther repository ppa:videolan/master-daily this was the repo i used

Comment: @hbeast As already commented, that PPA is the source of your problem.